# Embedded Lp spaces

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $L^\infty(Ω,F,P)$ be the vector space of bounded random variables $(X ∈ L^\infty (Ω,F,P)$ means that there exists a constant *C* such that $|X(ω)|≤C$, a.s.$)$. Show that $$L^\infty(Ω,F,P)⊂L^2(Ω,F,P)⊂L^1(Ω,F,P)$$

Comment: $P$ presumably is a probability measure. You could just use   comparison tests. For the second inclusion, given $f\in L_2$, consider the sets where $|f|\le 1$ and where $|f|>1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a consequence of Holder inequality
$$
E[|XY|]\leq E[|X|^p]^{1/p}E[|Y|^q]^{1/q}
$$

Comment: Thks, I got it for $L^2 \subset L^1$ (that is Cauchy-Schwartz as particular case of Holder) but not understood how $L^\infty \subset L^2$. Does $1/p+1/q=1$ holds?

Comment: Yes for $L^\infty$ you don't need to be 'fancy' :-P. But the same is true for general $q$ and then you need Holder, isn't it?

Comment: Got it! Anyway, is there a way to prove it without using Holder?

Comment: You don't need Holder to show merely set inclusion (Holder does, however, does give you the inequality between the norms).

Comment: To wit: for $\infty\ne q>p$, we have $\int |f|^p=\int_{[\,|f|\le 1\,]} |f|^p +\int_{[\,|f|> 1\,]} |f|^p\ \le\ \int_{[\,|f|\le 1\,]} 1 +\int_{[\,|f|> 1\,]} |f|^q$. So if the measure space is finite, then $f\in L_q$ implies $f\in L_p$.